# How can we transform written number to number in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, numbers, letter

For example the input is three hundred and twenty six and the output is 326.
I have already tried to write all  word of specific numbers like one,two,hundred,... in an array and the same for the integers . So they will have the same index like
word[0] is "one" and integer[0] is 1
But after that nothing works .

Comment: Is there a range of written numbers you are required to support? Or should your solution correctly transform any valid written number sequence?

Comment: There is a problem in the code you didn't show. That's all we can tell with the information you gave us. [Edit] and show a [mcve]. Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend starting with constructing a grammar. Here is an idea on how it can be done:

```
T :== t | td | d | x
H :== dh | dh&T 

d - digit
x - ten, eleven or twelve
t - twenty - ninety
h - hundred
& - and
T - 1-99
H - 1-999
```

Note that this may be slightly incorrect because English is not my native language. But it shows how to construct a grammar.

So 326 could then be constructed by H -> dh&T -> dh&td

An expanded grammar to include thousands could look like this:

```
A :== Ha | HaH

a - thousand
```

312108 could be constructed with A -> HaH -> dh&Tadh&T -> dh&xadh&d